# exec(open) function in Pycharm 'Python Console' NOT executing 'if __name__ == '__main__' block

Tags: python, pycharm, exec

I am trying to understand how exec(open) function works and have hit the following issue. Here's a simplified code to explain the problem.

Module1.py

```
print(11)

def func():
    print(12)

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    func()
```

So, when i run this module from terminal window, using 'python Module1.py', i get the output as

```
C:\projects>python Module1.py
11
12
```

but, when i execute it using exec(open) function from the Python Console/Interpreter as this 'exec(open('Module1.py').read())', then the output is

```
>>> exec(open('Module1.py').read())
11
```

Question is : why is the "if __name__ == __main__" block not getting executed when using exec function?

Comment: Because you're not executing it from main, ie. `__name__!='__main__'` right now

Comment: What version of python are you using? I've just tested on 3.6 and 2.7.13 and it works perfectly. Perhaps this is a Windows-specific issue?

Comment: @Alan I am using Python 3.5.2.

Comment: @Alan I am using Python 3.5.2. Based on your comment, I realized that there might be a difference in the way 'Python Console' in PyCharm editor is treating the exec(open) than it is treated by Interpreter in IDLE. I tried executing the code from Python IDLE and the outcome prints 12 from the if `__name__` block. This confirms that 'Python Console' window in PyCharm behaves differently which was causing the issue for me. I would cross-check on Python IDLE going forward whenever in doubt. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running code in PyCharm is not necessarily the same as running the code in the proper Python console.

As you mention in your comment, if you get odd results in PyCharm it's worth going back to the console and checking the output.

Based on the results, PyCharm seems to be running as "main" and any code you are running via PyCharm seems to not be considered module main.